# summary and plot for multiple subgroups(more columns)

Tags: r, plot, hmisc

I am interested in two things 1) Summary for multiple subgroups in the same table and 2) dotplot for the subgroups based on the summary generated in step1.

For example ,

if this is my dataset

```
     data("pbc")
```

I like to generate summary of cholesterol (`chol`), by  `sex`, `stage`, `ascites` and `spiders`  for two treatment levels 1, 2

```
     table(pbc$trt)
     1    2   
     158  154
```

I can do this separately like this.

```
     library(Hmisc)
     
     summary(chol ~ sex + stage + ascites + spiders, data = subset(pbc, trt=1))
     summary(chol ~ sex + stage + ascites + spiders, data = subset(pbc, trt=2))
```

This creates two separate summaries.

Two different corresponding plots

```
plot(summary(chol ~ sex + stage + ascites + spiders, data = subset(pbc, trt=1)))

plot(summary(chol ~ sex + stage + ascites + spiders, data = subset(pbc, trt=2)))
```

I like the summaries to be in one table , two columns 1 column for `trt=1` and 2nd column for `trt=2`

|  |  | N | chol (trt=1) | chol (trt=2) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| sex | m | .. | ..... . | .... .. |
|  | f | .. | ..... . | .... .. |

And the plot side by side. 1st plot for trt=1 , second plot for trt=2

[image]

Kindly suggest suggest how to scale the Hmisc:::summary.formula , summary function to 1) show summaries by subgroups side-by-side 2) Plot the summaries side-by-side. Thanks.

Comment: Can you add the code you used to generate these plots?

Comment: @jrcalabrese, I am unable to create those plots side by side. So thats my question, how to ?

Comment: Did you write any code to generate the plots separately/individually, or did someone else create those plots?

Comment: @jrcalabrese, generated it individually, separately.

Comment: Can you post the code you used to generate the plots individually?

Comment: @jrcalabrese, sure, I have updated my question section with the code for plots. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please note that your current summaries and plots are identical; despite using `subset` with the two levels of `trt`, your two posted plots are identical. You can use `filter` to definitively filter by the levels of `trt`.

First, I prefer `gtsummary` with my tables, since you can use `tbl_continuous` to make one singular table instead of trying to combine two tables. Second, you will likely encounter difficulty trying to combine your two plots since you're using base R plotting functions on `Hmisc` summary objects. Even trying to save each plot to an object will result in `NULL`. In the long run, it may be easier to recreate each plot using `ggplot` and combining with `cowplot::plot_grid`.

```
library(survival)
library(Hmisc)

# create combined summary
library(gtsummary)
library(tidyverse)

data(pbc)
df <- pbc %>%
  select(id, trt, chol, sex, stage, ascites, spiders) %>%
  mutate(across(c(sex, stage, ascites, spiders), as.factor)) %>%
  mutate(trt = factor(trt)) %>%
  mutate(chol = as.numeric(chol))

dftrt1 <- df %>% filter(trt == 1)
dftrt2 <- df %>% filter(trt == 2)

df %>%
  select(trt, chol, sex, stage, ascites, spiders) %>%
  tbl_continuous(variable = chol,
                 digits = everything() ~ 2,
                 statistic = everything() ~ "{mean}",
                 label = list(sex ~ "Sex", 
                              stage ~ "Stage", 
                              ascites ~ "Ascites", 
                              spiders ~ "Spiders"),
                 by = trt)
```

[image]

```
# create combined plot
library(cowplot)
p1 <- dftrt1 %>%
  select(-trt) %>% pivot_longer(cols = -c(id, chol)) %>% group_by(name, value) %>%
  summarise(chol = mean(chol, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = value, y = chol, fill = factor(value))) + 
  geom_point() + coord_flip() +
  facet_wrap(~name, scales = "free_y", nrow = 4, strip.position = "top") +
  theme(panel.spacing = unit(0, "lines"),
          panel.border = element_rect(fill = NA),
          strip.background = element_blank(),
          axis.title.y = element_blank(),
          legend.position = "none",
          strip.placement = "outside") +
  ggtitle("trt = 1") + theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))

p2 <- dftrt2 %>%
  select(-trt) %>% pivot_longer(cols = -c(id, chol)) %>% group_by(name, value) %>%
  summarise(chol = mean(chol, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = value, y = chol, fill = factor(value))) + 
  geom_point() + coord_flip() +
  facet_wrap(~name, scales = "free_y", nrow = 4, strip.position = "top") +
  theme(panel.spacing = unit(0, "lines"),
        panel.border = element_rect(fill = NA),
        strip.background = element_blank(),
        axis.title.y = element_blank(),
        legend.position = "none",
        strip.placement = "outside") +
  ggtitle("trt = 2") + theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))

plot_grid(p1, p2, ncol = 2)
```

[image]